# How to convert UTF8 to cp1252 correctly (1.8.7)

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, iconv, cp1252

I am not sure how to tell `Iconv` to transcode my strings to readable output.

Example: I am converting a "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON" [U+0160](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/160/index.htm), rendered as `Š`.

`Iconv.conv('cp1252', 'UTF8', 'Š'`) however returns `"\212"`

I would expect it to return the equivalent cp1252 character, `0x8A`, also rendered as `Š`. However the printed result is still `"\212"` - it's octal representation (`\212` is octal for `0x8A` or `138`).

I have also tried some more exotic encoding instructions like `cp1252//IGNORE//TRANSLIT`, with the same output.

What am I doing wrong, and how should it be done?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Casper says, the console output should render the character correctly, but it doesn't. Perhaps I just don't know how to set it to accept cp1252.

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to do it - I am working on an Ubuntu 13.04 and both the regular bash with irb and RubyMine's built-in console display the output as `"\212"`

The output of `locale` is `en_US.UTF8` for all values.

`Iconv.conv('cp1252', 'UTF8', 'Š').inspect` prints `"\"\\212\""`

`Iconv.conv('cp1252', 'UTF8', 'Š').each_byte { |b| p b }` prints `138` and `"\212"`

Comment: Sounds correct to me. `puts "\212"` should output what you need when your terminal is configured to cp1252?

Comment: Casper is right - you have to get the string from Ruby to a device that knows how to display it correctly. Ruby doesn't render the glyph for you, and if in doubt `irb` or `inspect` will output the escaped octal so at least you can see unambiguously what is in the string.

Comment: @Casper that's what I expected, however I am getting literally "\212", that's why I'm asking. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You're inspecting the value. From IRB:

```
$ irb
>> "\x8A"
=> "\212"
```

This is the same as:

```
>> puts "\x8A".inspect
"\212"
=> nil
```

Instead you have to print the value:

```
>> puts "\x8A"
�
=> nil
```

My terminal displays "�" because 0x8A is an invalid sequence in UTF-8 (my terminal's encoding). If I change my terminal to CP-1252 it displays "Š".